# Python: How to cast a list item into a Class?

Tags: python

I have added instances from a Class ("Scores") into a list.
Here is the content of the list:

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Scores object at 0x7fa2520154e0>
<__main__.Scores object at 0x7fa252015c30>
<__main__.Scores object at 0x7fa252016080>
<__main__.Scores object at 0x7fa252016110>
<__main__.Scores object at 0x7fa2520161a0>
<__main__.Scores object at 0x7fa252016260>
```

I'm looking for a way to cast the "item" in the Scores class when iterating over it. Coming from a Java background, I've tried with:

```
for item in mylist:
    print(((Scores)item).wins)
```

But that doesn't work:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

I'd need to cast back to the "Scores" class so that I can use the Class attributes (e.g. wins)
Any help?

Comment: Did you try `print(item.wins)`

Comment: Good Grief it works! How does on earth python can do it without knowing the Class type?! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item.wins)
```

Let me know